# Disable scheduling on second instance of same project on AWS

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, scheduled-tasks, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have 2 instances of the same deployment/project on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

Both contain a Laravel project which contains scheduling code which runs various commands which can be found in the schedule method/function of the Kernel.php class within 'app/Console' - the problem I have is that if a command runs from one instance then it will also run the command from the second instance which is not what I want to happen.

What I would like to happen is that the commands get run from only one instance and not the other. How do I achieve this in the easiest way possible?

Is there a Laravel package which could help me achieve this?

Comment: Do your applications share a cache server, e.g. a single Redis instance?

Comment: Yes they both use the same single Redis instance

Answer (score 1):

**From Laravel 5.6:**

Laravel provides a [`onOneServer`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#running-tasks-on-one-server) method which you can use if your applications share a single cache server. You could use something like [ElastiCache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/) to host Redis or Memcached and use it as your cache server for both of your application instances. Then you would be able to use the `onOneServer` method like this:

```
$schedule->command('report:generate')
                ->fridays()
                ->at('17:00')
                ->onOneServer();
```

**For older versions of Laravel:**

You could use the [jdavidbakr/multi-server-event](https://packagist.org/packages/jdavidbakr/multi-server-event) package. Once you have it set up you should be able to use it like:

```
$schedule->command('inspire')
    ->daily()
    ->withoutOverlappingMultiServer();
```

Comment: Looks really good. Unfortunately, I forgot to mention earlier that the project is Laravel 5.3 and therefore I don't think it will work with that version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue to run some cronjobs (nothing related to Laravel) and I found a nice solution (don't remember where I found it)

What I do is check if the instance running the code is the first instance on the Auto Scaling Group, if it's the first then I execute the command otherwise just exit.

This is the way it's implemented:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
INSTANCE_ID=`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id 2>/dev/null`
REGION=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document 2>/dev/null | jq -r .region`

# Find the Auto Scaling Group name from the Elastic Beanstalk environment
ASG=`aws ec2 describe-tags --filters "Name=resource-id,Values=$INSTANCE_ID" \
    --region $REGION --output json | jq -r '.[][] | select(.Key=="aws:autoscaling:groupName") | .Value'`

# Find the first instance in the Auto Scaling Group
FIRST=`aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --auto-scaling-group-names $ASG \
    --region $REGION --output json | \
    jq -r '.AutoScalingGroups[].Instances[] | select(.LifecycleState=="InService") | .InstanceId' | sort | head -1`

# If the instance ids are the same exit 0
[ "$FIRST" = "$INSTANCE_ID" ]
```

Try implementing those calls using PHP and it should work.